# Why is process not part of expected process group?

Tags: linux, process, process-groups

I'm learning about the relationship between processes, process groups (and sessions) in Linux.

I compiled the following program...

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  char buf[128];
  time_t now;
  struct tm* tm_now;
  while ( true )
  {
    time( &now );
    tm_now = localtime( &now );
    strftime( buf, sizeof(buf), "%a, %d %b %Y %T %z", tm_now );
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    sleep(5);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

... to `a.out` and ran it as a background process like so...

```bash
a.out &
```

[This website](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html) says the following...

> Every process is member of a unique process group, identified by its
>   process group ID. (When the process is created, it becomes a member of
>   the process group of its parent.) By convention, the process group ID
>   of a process group equals the process ID of the first member of the
>   process group, called the process group leader.

Per my reading, the first sentence conflicts with the in-parentheses content: is a process a member of a *unique* process group, or is it a member of the process group *of its parent*?

I tried to investigate with `ps`...

```bash
ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,command | grep "PGID\|a.out"
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
24714 23890 24714 23890 ./a.out
```

This tells me my `a.out` process is pid `24714`, spawned from parent pid `23890` and part of program group `24714`. To begin with, I don't understand why this pgid matches the pid.

Next, I tried to investigate the parent process...

```bash
ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,command | grep "PGID\|23890"
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
23890 11892 23890 23890 bash
24714 23890 24714 23890 ./a.out
```

It makes sense to me that the parent process of my `a.out` is `bash`. At first I thought "*bash's pid matches its pgid - that must be because it's the process group leader. Maybe that makes sense because bash is kind of the "first thing" that got run, from which I ran my process.*" But that reasoning doesn't make sense because `a.out`'s pgid also matches its own pid.

Why doesn't `a.out`'s pgid equal `bash`'s pgid? That's what I would have expected, from my understanding of the quote.

Can someone clarify the relationship between pids and pgids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no conflict; a process will by default be in a unique process group which is the process group of its parent:

```
$ cat pg.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    fork();
    printf("pid=%d pgid=%d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());
}
$ make pg
cc     pg.c   -o pg
$ ./pg 
pid=12495 pgid=12495
pid=12496 pgid=12495
$
```

The `fork` splits our process into parent (`12495`) and child (`12496`), and the child belongs to the unique process group of the parent (`12495`). `bash` departs from this because it issues additional system calls:

```
$ echo $$
12366
$
```

And then in another terminal we run:

```
$ strace -f -o blah -p 12366
```

And then back in the first terminal:

```
$ ./pg
pid=12676 pgid=12676
pid=12677 pgid=12676
$
```

And then we <kbd>control+c</kbd> the `strace`, and inspect the system calls:

```
$ egrep 'exec|pgid' blah
12366 setpgid(12676, 12676)             = 0
12676 setpgid(12676, 12676 <unfinished ...>
12676 <... setpgid resumed> )           = 0
12676 execve("./pg", ["./pg"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
12676 write(1, "pid=12676 pgid=12676\n", 21 <unfinished ...>
12677 write(1, "pid=12677 pgid=12676\n", 21 <unfinished ...>
```

`bash` has used the `setpgid` call to set the process group, thus placing our `pg` process into process group unrelated to that of the shell. (`setsid(2)` would be another way to tweak the process group, if you're hunting for system calls.)

Comment: Do I have this straight? The strace tells us bash (pid 12366) leads to creation (I guess `fork`ing) of child process (pid 12676). Then bash calls `setpgid` to set the pgid of the child process (12676) to 12676. But what's with the second call to `setpgid(12676, 12676)` that seems to be performed by process 12676? Then lastly, bash `execve`s the program to kick off the process.

Comment: And I guess the explicit call to `setpgid` would be the reason why `pg`'s pgid doesn't match bash's pgid. As opposed to the parent/child processes from the `pg` executable that demonstrate the "expected" behavior because there is no explicit call to `setpgid()` (?)

Comment: There's a `fork` (`clone`, actually) not shown where `bash` splits into 12366 and 12676. The call complications aside, it's mostly to show that `bash` does not follow the expected behavior because it makes an extra system call.

Comment: `bash` puts the child into a new process group to implement job control. Each job has to be a separate process group from the shell so it can be moved from foreground to background.

Answer (score 5):

Bash puts your program in its own process group as part of its job control handling. For example, from the bash manpage:

> To facilitate the implementation of the user interface to job control, the operating system  maintains  the
>          notion  of  a  current  terminal  process group ID.  Members of this process group (processes whose process
>          group ID is equal to the current terminal process group ID) receive keyboard-generated signals such as SIG‐
>          INT.  These processes are said to be in the foreground.  Background processes are those whose process group
>          ID differs from the terminal's; such processes are immune to keyboard-generated signals.   Only  foreground
>          processes  are  allowed  to read from or, if the user so specifies with stty tostop, write to the terminal.
>          Background processes which attempt to read from (write to when stty tostop is in effect) the  terminal  are
>          sent  a  SIGTTIN  (SIGTTOU)  signal  by  the  kernel's  terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the
>          process.

Also the part about `set -m`:

> Monitor  mode.  Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for interactive shells
>                         on systems that support it (see JOB CONTROL above).  All processes run in a separate process
>                         group.  When a background job completes, the shell prints a line containing its exit status.

So, if you want the behavior you're expecting, you can:

1. Use `fork` inside your code, to create a process without bash doing it.
2. Use `set +m` to turn off monitor mode in bash. This will break things like `fg`, though.