# Can Ctrl+C send the SIGINT signal to multiple processes?

Tags: linux, signals, process-groups

I have read that when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  a `SIGINT` signal will be sent to the *foreground process group*.

Can you give me an example of how I can have two or more processes in the *foreground process group*, because I want to see if all processes will terminate if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Possibly related to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018586/spawn-parallel-processes-in-foreground

Comment: Minimal runnable example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/why-is-sigint-not-propagated-to-child-process-when-sent-to-its-parent-process/465112#465112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [new processes all belong to the same process group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363126/why-is-process-not-part-of-expected-process-group), that of the parent process, have a process start a bunch of processes (`fork`), and then with appropriate logging and a delay, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. They all eat a `SIGINT`.

```
$ perl -E 'fork for 1..2;say "ima $$"; $SIG{INT}=sub{die "woe $$\n"}; sleep 999'
ima 80920
ima 80922
ima 80921
ima 80923
^Cwoe 80920
woe 80922
woe 80921
woe 80923
$
```

(Add `strace` or `sysdig` or such to see the system calls or signals involved.)

Comment: How can a process start more than one process, I mean wouldn't the parent process block until the first child process is terminated?

Comment: `fork` makes two processes from one process. The parent can but need not block by calling some `wait` function. The above `perl` processes do not block on anything, they just all go to sleep.

Comment: I can also just make the parent process start only one child process, and then press `Ctrl+C` one time to terminate both the parent and child processes (I tried it and it worked).

Answer (score 2):

A [pipeline is one job](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_202), with multiple processes:

```
(cat ; echo foo >&2) | (cat ; echo bar >&2 )
```

If you end the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you get the `foo` and `bar` output, if you kill the pipeline with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, neither is printed.

Answer (score 0):

One example:

```
bash-4.3$ ( ( sleep 2 & (ps -Hfj | sh -c cat; perl -MPOSIX -E 'say tcgetpgrp 0'; sleep 5;:);:);:)
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas 18631  3848 18631 18631  0 12:51 pts/7    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas  2184 18631  2184 18631  0 21:00 pts/7    00:00:00   bash --norc
chazelas  2430  2184  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00     bash --norc
chazelas  2431  2430  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00       bash --norc
chazelas  2432  2431  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00         sleep 2
chazelas  2433  2431  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00         bash --norc
chazelas  2434  2433  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00           ps -Hfj
chazelas  2435  2433  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00           sh -c cat
chazelas  2436  2435  2430 18631  0 21:07 pts/7    00:00:00             cat
2430
```

At the time `ps` was running, there were 7 processes in the 2430 process group: 3 subshell processes (`bash`), one running `ps`, one running `sh`, one running `cat`, one running `sleep 1`. Later on, the processes spawned to execute `perl` and `sleep 5` would also be in that same group.

`tcgetpgrp()` confirms that 2430 was indeed the foreground process group of the terminal device, so upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, all the processes in that group would receive a SIGINT.