# Why the process run by the shell does not inherit the shell's Process Group ID?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process-groups

I have read that when *Process A* start *Process B*, then *Process B* will inherit *Process A*'s Process Group ID.

I tested this by making `bash` execute the `cat` program, but I found out that `bash` and `cat` had two different Process Group ID, why is that?

Comment: Is this of any help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139222/why-is-the-pgid-of-my-child-processes-not-the-pid-of-the-parent?rq=1

Comment: `bash` fiddles with the process group for job control. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363126/why-is-process-not-part-of-expected-process-group

Answer (score 0):

The sid (session id) should be consistent.

When bash runs a command, it generally assigns the PGID to the first process.
If its a pipeline, all the piped commands  have the same PGID as the first process.