# Will a child process be in a different process group than the parent process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I always thought that a child process will be in the same process group as the parent process. But I have read the following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548823/use-and-meaning-of-session-and-process-group-in-unix):

> if you run some_app from the shell, the shell creates a new process
>   group for it, and makes that the foreground process group of the
>   session.

I made `bash` execute `cat`, and I found out that `cat` indeed has a different process group id than `bash`. Is this a `bash` only behavior to have the child process be in a different group?

Comment: After `fork()` the child process  is in the same group as the parent.  The child can set itself to a new group (perhaps before `exec()`-ing something else), or it can stay within the parent's group.  It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Satō Katsura So in my case, `cat` has set itself to a new group?

Comment: No, `bash` did a `fork()`, then the child set itself to a new group, then the same child `exec()`-ed your `cat`.

Comment: Shells do this as part of job handling -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363126/why-is-process-not-part-of-expected-process-group